# SELECT all Orders and only the second OrderItem

Tags: sql, select

I need to find only the second ordered item for all orders? I have an Order table linked to an OrderItems table, a one to many relationship.

The OrderItems has a column PriorityId but for any given order the OrderItems.PriorityId can be a 3 or 4 digit number and they don't always run sequentially.

I can do this for a single Order using OFFSET 1 ROW, FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY

but I can't workout how to do this when I select all the orders in the Order table.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: can you provide the sample dataset and what exactly you are trying to achieve ??

Answer (score 2):

If you want the second priority item *per order*, then you probably want `row_number()`:

```
select oi.*
from (select oi.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_id order by priority) as seqnum
      from orderitems oi
     ) oi
where seqnum = 2;
```